# How to merge the results of a web service to a dynamic type, can I use Linq's Zip or a Lambda function to find the row to merge

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I can't seem to get the syntax right to find an original object to add data from a web service to it.  Would someone be able to help me fix my syntax, or explain how I should be doing this?

I'm getting a list of addresses that I'm sending to a web service for processing.  The list of addresses could also contain 0 to many unknown columns that should be retained, but not sent to the web service, so I'm using the dynamic type, which allows me to retain all the unknown rows and easily add the data coming back from the web service.  This is how the data comes into the handler on the server side:

```
dynamic userAddresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

A simple example of the userAddresses object after deserialization would looks like this:

```
{
"Addresses": [
{
  "id": "",
  "address": "1 Royal Way",
  "city": "Kansas City",
  "state": "MO",
  "zipcode": ""
}
]
}
```

for an incoming json string like this:

```
"{\"Addresses\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"address\":\"1 Royal Way\",\"city\":\"Kansas City\",\"state\":\"MO\",\"zipcode\":\"\"}]}"
```

I then send 500 addresses at a time to the web service in a threaded fashion.  I've got the results back and I'm stuck trying to find the original item.  So I get web service results back that will be in a response variable.  Both have an id field that has to be unique.  This is what I have so far, but am getting a unknown type of variable for e.

```
foreach (var response in webServiceResponses)
{
  dynamic request = userAddresses.Addresses.Find(e => e.id == response.id); // Error on e.id
  // Now enhance original request with addition data return by web service
}
```

In my searches for an answer I came across a Linq function for Zip, that might be a better way to go if it works with the dynamic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dump the `dynamic` object altogether; it adds unnecessary complexity.  I would deserialize the json string into an array of anonymous types like this:

```
var userAddresses = 
    JObject
    .Parse(json)["Addresses"]
    .Select(x => new { 
        Id = Int32.Parse(x["id"].ToString()),
        Properties = 
            x
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(y => y.Name != "id")
            .Select(y => new { y.Name, Value = y.Value.ToString() })
    });
```

That will give you an array anonymous types that looks like this:

```
{
  "Id":1,
  "Properties":[
    {
      "Name":"address",
      "Value":"1 Royal Way"
    },
    {
      "Name":"city",
      "Value":"Kansas City"
    },
    {
      "Name":"state",
      "Value":"MO"
    },
    {
      "Name":"zipcode",
      "Value":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can pair your responses with those like this:

```
var pairs = 
    webServiceResponses
    .Join(
        userAddresses,
        response => response.Id,
        address => address.Id,
        (response, address) => new { Response = response, Address = address });
```

Now you can operate on these any way you like.

## Edit Based On Comments

Give this class a try:

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

With this code (slightly modified from above):

```
IEnumerable<UserAddress> userAddresses =
    JObject
    .Parse(json)["Addresses"]
    .Select(x => new UserAddress()
        {
            Id = Int32.Parse(x["id"].ToString()),
            Properties =
                x
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(y => y.Name != "id")
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value.ToString())
        });

var pairs =
    webServiceResponses
    .Join(
        userAddresses,
        response => response.Id,
        address => address.Id,
        (response, address) => new { Response = response, Address = address });

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    // Add each key\value pair in pair.Response to pair.Address.Properties.
}
```

Comment: Instead of joining the two, would it be possible to pull the key value pairs I need out of the web service response and then add to the anonymous array where the id's equal?

Comment: Anonymous types seem great but makes in difficult to pass between methods. How would this be converted to a strongly typed object so that I can use in methods later in processing?  I'm currently going with `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> userInput = userAddresses.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Properties.ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value));`, but that makes a complete copy of it.  I would prefer something that can just cast it.  Is that possible?

Comment: If you plan on passing this between methods it needs to be strongly typed.  Obviously the entire thing cannot be strongly typed because of the unknown columns but you can create a class with the know properties strongly typed and then a property to act as a property bag that will be a collection of the dynamic values.  I think you are on the right path with the `Dictionary`.  I will make some quick changes to my answer.  If that does not work we can drop into a chat.

Comment: I'm liking that approach, I'm unsure how to re serialize the strongly typed object back to the client however.  I've been using `response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userAddresses);`, which isn't flat, this is closer `response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userAddresses, new KeyValuePairConverter());`, but that puts id on a different level.  It should go back to the client in just a simple list of key:value.  What is the trick for this?  Is it a custom converter?  Or can it be done with a Linq/Lambda expression?

Comment: Well, you could remove the portion of the `Where` clause that is excluding the `id` from the property bag (and any other strongly typed properties you may have added here).  This will mean all your strongly typed properties would be duplicated.  They would exist once as properties on the class and again in the property bag.  If there are not that many it will not have a big impact.  Then to serialize it you could do this: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userAddresses.Select(x => x.Properties))`

Comment: Or, during your initial deserialization you could simply deserialize the json string into a dictionary rather than a custom class and perform all your operations on the dictionary.  That makes me feel kind of gross, though.  Using a dictionary exclusively will basically eliminate any of the benefits of compile time checking.  Your server side code will rely heavily on magic strings.  But it will eliminate duplication of a few fields in your user addresses and be easy to serialize.

Comment: The final option, I think, is to roll your own serializer for your custom class.  I would not go that route unless you really do find the duplication of properties to be intolerable.  `Newtonsoft.Json` provides plenty of hooks to plug in your custom serialization.  I have done it myself in the past.

Comment: A duplicate field here or there isn't going to kill me.  For what this is, that idea works great!  Now the only issue is the client expects CamelCase and  the deserialization to the dictionary moved everything to lowercase.  Is there a way on the deserialization to CamelCase the Key name?  Also wanted to add that all these options are much better than my original path with a dynamic!

Comment: I am not seeing that in my test project.  If the string is coming over the wire in camel case then deserialization should not modify the case.  This is something that would be handled by the `ContractResolver`; maybe there is a custom contract resolver on the server side.  If you continue to have this issue then I would recommend opening a new question.